# I keep getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, dns, disconnect

I'm using a desktop with a wired connection (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS).
I keep getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET (on chrome and other browsers).
Running: "sudo service network-manager restart" in terminal solves the issue for a few minutes.
I need a permanent solution...

Edit#1:
I haven't installed any firewall.
Firewall:
ufw status
Results:
Status: inactive

Edit#2:
Tried to flush dns using:
sudo systemd-resolve --statistics
Results:
DNSSEC supported by current servers: no

Transactions
Current Transactions: 0
Total Transactions: 15512

Cache
Current Cache Size: 115
Cache Hits: 2104
Cache Misses: 6639

DNSSEC Verdicts
Secure: 0
Insecure: 0
Bogus: 0
Indeterminate: 0

Comment: Please edit your post with more details, it is way too ambiguous. Firewall status? IP tables rules/have you tried a DNS flush? We need more information...

Comment: Thanks 4 the reply. Please tell me if there's anything else I can specify. I'm new to linux :)

Comment: Can you try using a different network manager than the default one? That might help...? Just something to try.

Comment: I've tried to google and find out how to do that. Couldn't find how.
I'm prity sure this is some configuration issue.